# Replace values from one row to another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I got this code

```
UPDATE TASK tas1
SET TARGET_WORK_QTY = (SELECT REMAIN_WORK_QTY 
                       FROM TASK tas2
                       WHERE tas1.TASK_ID = tas2.TASK_ID
                         AND PROJ_ID = 884)
```

and it is supposed to re-write values from one row to another (based on the same task_id and project = 884), but it kinda works differently. i am using oracle 11g.

example table

> id  value1 value2 
>   1    aaa      zzz 
>   2    bbb      xxx 
>   3    ccc      aaa

i would like to get the following result (replace values from value 1 to value 2):

> id  value1 value2 
>   1    aaa      aaa 
>   2    bbb      bbb 
>   3    ccc      ccc

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: hello, thank you. i am using oracle 11

Comment: @Aleksej, there is one and only one table whose name is **TASK** with two different aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample data and needed result, it seems that you simply need:

```
update task
set value2 = value1
```

For example:

```
SQL> create table task(id, value1, value2) as (
  2      select 1, 'aaa', 'zzz' from dual union all
  3      select 2, 'bbb', 'xxx' from dual union all
  4      select 3, 'ccc', 'aaa' from dual
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> update task set value2 = value1;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from task;

        ID VAL VAL
---------- --- ---
         1 aaa aaa
         2 bbb bbb
         3 ccc ccc

SQL>
```